# Objective-C - How To Remove Characters From a String?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, formatting, nsdecimalnumber

I have a UILabel that has a formatted String (formatted for currency), so there is a dollar sign, $21.34.

In the core data entity the attribute is of a type double, I am using an NSDecimalNumber to save to the database.

```
    self.purchase.name = self.nameTextField.text;
    NSString *string = self.amountLabel.text
    NSDecimalNumber *newAmount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"%@", string); // THIS RETURNS NaN, because of dollar sign i think

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.purchase.managedObjectContext;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
```

Anyway, I need this to not be NaN, so my thinking is to remove the dollar sign, but i do not know how to do that, or perhaps there is a better way to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    NSString* cleanedString = [costString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]];
```

Is a lot more robust than the one above (and I think it will handle commas, too)

Answer (score 5):

OK, so i ended up using this code and it works for me

```
        NSString *inString = self.amountLabel.text;
    NSMutableString *outString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:inString.length];

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:inString];
    NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@".0123456789"];

    while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO)
    {
        NSString *buffer;
        if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&buffer])
        {
            [outString appendString:buffer];
        }
        else {
            [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"%@", outString);
    NSDecimalNumber *amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:outString];

    self.purchase.amount = amount;
```

Comment: UGH this is total overkill.  You can use an `NSNumberFormatter` to remove the formatting around the string and give it back to you as an `NSNumber`.  Your code will also break any time you come across a currency that places the sign to the right of the numbers.  An `NSNumberFormatter` would correctly handle it.

Comment: The place of the currency sign does not matter, rather the code is looking for any char that does not match the NSCharacterSet and then removing it from the string if it's not in the set

Answer (score 2):

To add to @justin's answer:

```
[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]
```

won't remove commas.  So you can combine it with:

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString
```

and use:

```
    NSString* cleanedString = [[costString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""] 
stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]];
```

to get a cleaned number suitable for arithmetic (e.g. *£1,005.33* becomes *1005.33*)

Answer (score 1):

Really you should have your value which is a simple number, like a float if dealing in currency. Then you should have a string that represents your value. You could use an NSNumberFormatter to get from the value to the string, like you say you have, but you shouldn't be relying on the string as your only source of that value.

Also, NSDecimalNumber is probably overkill for representing something like currency. NSDecimalNumber is better suited for dealing with numbers in scientific notation.

A simple NSNumber object will be good enough for working with currency, using something like `numberWithDouble:`.

Comment: Please do not say that NSDecimalNumber is overkill. It is exactly the right thing to use for many applications, especially when dealing with financial data.

Comment: From the docs: "NSDecimalNumber, an immutable subclass of NSNumber, provides an object-oriented wrapper for doing base-10 arithmetic. An instance can represent any number that can be expressed as mantissa x 10^exponent where mantissa is a decimal integer up to 38 digits long, and exponent is an integer from –128 through 127." -- NSNumber is more than sufficient for dealing with financial data.

Comment: A number format in which simple numbers like 0.1 are not representable without possibly introducing rounding errors is not very suitable for many applications dealing with financial data. Floating point is great for many things but accurate financial calculation is not one of them.

Comment: I am sorry, but NSDecimalNumber is the correct type when dealing with Currency, thank you

Comment: NSNumber is capable of representing numbers far more precise than just 0.1.

Comment: @Jasarien: yes. But it is not capable of representing many simple numbers exactly (0.1 is one such example). Regardless of the precision of the fp unit.

Comment: I hope you're joking. If it's money, use `NSDecimalNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove the $ sign. why not just do the following before dealing with the number

```
NSString *newStringValue = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining @justin's and @leafy's answer:

```
[[@"$1,000" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]];
```

This will give you 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSDecimalNumber *newAmount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:[string substringFromIndex:1]];
```