# Removing \ from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am working on NSString where I am getting this string

```
 "[  {    \"36\" : 142  }",
        "  {    \"38\" : 149  }",
        "  {    \"39\" : -1  }",
        "  {    \"40\" : -1  }",
        "  {    \"41\" : 163  }",
        "  {    \"42\" : -1  }",
        "  {    \"84\" : 302  }]"
```

I want to remove all \ from this string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C - How To Remove Characters From a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289928/objective-c-how-to-remove-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: first it is not a string its a dictionary and you have " " in string, first parse your string, then remove \ from individual strings . "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString" that doesn't work directly for this

Comment: It looks like escaped JSON inside of string literals separated with commas, probably inside of array literal? Could you provide more details on the usage?

Comment: Yes I have searched but not found satisfied answer that is why I posted question.

Comment: @PradumnaPatil please update your question.

Comment: Please write full code where you want to replace the \. Not just a string

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace '\' character with NULL character.

```
NSString *newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
```

Comment: Hi did you tried this in a real example...?? I have tried but it is not working...

Answer (score 1):

**Approach One:**

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
```

**Approach Two:**

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

I'm curious if approach 2 works for parsing the string into a json?

Comment: Approch one contain \" as a string but I want to remove only \ from my string So it does not work for me.

Comment: I have only single backslash not double backslash so it does not working for me.

Comment: The double backslash is escaping the single backslash, see more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931942/nsstring-backslash-escaping

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `\\` with `BLANK SPACE` using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` method. Below is the example...

```
NSString *yourString = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
```

Comment: Why not simply `"\\"` for `""`?

Comment: That’s maybe the problem. The question was how to remove backslash.

Comment: Yup you are right. Just update my answer.. Is it okay now..?

Comment: Almost. Update also the first sentence, now it’s inconsistent.

Comment: I have only single backslash not double backslash so it does not working for me.

Comment: Have you tried in the form of code... 
When you want to assign a Double Quote or BackSlash in the string. You need to write \" for Double Quote and \\ for BackSlash... 
Understood.